# How to collect data from dynamically generated forms?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This is a web-app where the user creates orders on a client. The user should of course be able to add more than one product to an order. This is done by adding more dropdown-menus with a button. The information from the form is going to be inserted into two different tables in the data base, Orders and OrderLines. Order is all the general information about the order and orderLine is information about the product ordered. The issue arises when you have more than one product.

Currently I create an instance of both order and orderLine, but this will not work when there is more than one product. I have made a little jQuery script that counts the number of rows.

How do you tell the controller how many dropdown menus that has been generated so it can create the corresponding number of orderLine objects?

How can you make the name of the dropdown menus different so that the controller can assign the right products to the orderLine?

Irrelevant code omitted.

View

```
<div class="card-body">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("InsertOrder", "Add", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <div class="row-3">
        @Html.DropDownList("fromDBProducts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DBProducts"], "Velg produkt", new { @class = "form-control drop, insert-textbox" })
        @Html.TextBox("Price", null, new { @class = "form-control insert-textbox price-text", @placeholder = "kr" })
        <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
            <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
            @Html.TextBox("count", 1, new { @class = "count unselectable" })
            <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="add-product-btn"></button>
        </div>         
    <div class="row-7">
        <input type="submit" value="Fullfør ✓" class="btn btn-success" id="form-submit" />
    </div>
    }
</div>

 @* Template for appending dropdowns. *@
    <script id="template" type="text/template">
        <div class="row-3">
            @Html.DropDownList("fromDBProducts", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["DBProducts"], "Velg produkt", new { @class = "form-control drop, insert-textbox" })
            @Html.TextBox("Price", null, new { @class = "form-control insert-textbox price-text", @placeholder = "kr" })
            <div class="qty mt-5 counter-div">
                <span class="minus btn-secondary unselectable">-</span>
                @Html.TextBox("count", 1, new { @class = "count unselectable" })
                <span class="plus btn-secondary unselectable">+</span>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="remove-btn"></button>
        </div>

    </script>

@* Add dropdown menu based on template *@
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ($) {
            $('#add-product-btn').on('click', function (e) {
                $('.row-3:last').after($('#template').html());
            });

            $(document).on('click', '#remove-btn', function () {
                $(this).parent('div').remove();
            });
        });

@* Getting number of dropdown-divs *@
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(document).on('click', '#form-submit', function () {
                var rowCount = $('.row-3').length;
                return(rowCount);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult InsertOrder(FormCollection formCollection)
        {
            string productName = Request.Form["fromDBProducts"];
            Product thisProduct = null;

            foreach(Product product in db.Products)
            {
                if(product.Name == productName)
                {
                    thisProduct = product;
                    break;
                }
            }

            OrderLine orderLine = new OrderLine();

            orderLine.RecordCreated = DateTime.Now;
            orderLine.RecordDeleted = false;
            orderLine.OrderID = order.ID;
            orderLine.ProductID = thisProduct.ID;
            orderLine.ProductName = thisProduct.Name;

        //InsertMethodHere(orderLine)

            return RedirectToAction("Index", vm);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depending on how you want it to post, you need to give your from controls different names/ids.

So when adding the HTML replace the name of the ddl with Name[count]. Example fromDBProducts[0], fromDBProducts[1] etc

something like:

```
  $('.row-3:last').after($('#template').html().replace(/fromDBProducts/g,"fromDBProducts[" + rowCount +"]"));
```

Comment: I'll try this! Thanks for the answer.